# Error on Mongoose .populate when choosing specific fields; I think virtual has something to do with it

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I'm learning Mongoose and I'm trying out an exercise that is throwing an error I don't know what to do about.

I have a schema for "User" that has a pair of referenced arrays for "friends" (other Users) and "thoughts" (another schema). Both the User schema and Thought schema have virtual fields. When I use `.populate("thoughts")` and `.populate("friends")`, everything works as it should: I get in return each User with their thoughts and users populated. BUT when I try to specify only specific fields in the populate, I get a server error that seems to reference a virtual getter, even though that isn't one of the fields I'm populating.

Here is the schema for `User`:

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { options...} ,
    email: { options... },
    },
    thoughts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "thought" }],
    friends: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user"}],
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    id: false
  }
);
```

And here is the schema for `Thought`:

```
const thoughtSchema = new Schema(
  {
    thoughtText: { options... },
    createdAt: { options... },
    username: { options... },
    reactions: [reactionSchema]
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    id: false,
  }
);
```

Here is the getter for the thought virtual, which counts its reactions:

```
thoughtSchema.virtual("reactionCount").get(function () {
  return this.reactions.length;
});
```

Finally, here is the `findOne` with its populate schema:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.user })
      .populate("thoughts")
      .populate("friends");
```

As I've shown here, everything works fine, and I get something like this:

```
{
  "_id": "643db33e4a979154a6d6ded4",
  "username": "samwise",
  "email": "samwise@facebook.com",
  "thoughts": [
    {
      "_id": "643db33e4a979154a6d6dee6",
      "thoughtText": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit...",
      "createdAt": "2023-04-17T20:59:42.138Z",
      "username": "samwise",
      "reactions": [],
      "__v": 0,
      "reactionCount": 0
    }
  ],
  "friends": [.
    {
      "_id": "643db33e4a979154a6d6dee4",
      "username": "benhur",
      "email": "benhur@yahoo.com",
      "thoughts": [ "643db33e4a979154a6d6deef", "643db33e4a979154a6d6defe", "643db33e4a979154a6d6df07", "643db33e4a979154a6d6df13" ],
      "friends": [ "643db33e4a979154a6d6ded4", "643db33e4a979154a6d6ded6", "643db33e4a979154a6d6dede" ],
      "__v": 0,
      "thoughtCount": 4,
      "friendCount": 3
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0,
  "thoughtCount": 1,
  "friendCount": 1
}
```

BUT, if I change the `.populate` fields to limit what gets populated for each thought to:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.user })
      .populate("thoughts", "thoughtText createdAt")
      .populate("friends");
```

...then I get this error in the terminal:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at model.<anonymous> ((path)/models/Thought.js:56:25)
```

That line number is referencing the virtual getter for reactionCount. The same is true if I specify fields for "friends" (the error points to the virtual getter for `friendCount`). I have tried this other construction:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.user })
      .populate("thoughts",
         { path: "thought",
         select: "thoughtText" })
      .populate("friends");
```

...but I get the same error. Given the code the error points to, it appears perhaps there is something wrong with the getter?

Comment: ...and of course I found a way to do it, but with a caveat. If I change the virtual getter to check for the presence of the `friends` array, and if it doesn't exist return 0, then it gets around this and works...only it will always show me zero now on the populated field, even if the real value isn't 0. And it always shows the virtual fields even if I haven't identified them to include in the `populate`.